# Yahoo pipes filters return weird results

Tags: yahoo-pipes

My goal is to produce a system that will examine feeds from multiple web sites, look for certain key words related to the power industry, and then produce another feed that will alert me when those articles are posted.

Many of the words in question appear in other places too. I can't simply make a filter on "solar" because then I get lots of posts about astronomy. I really need "solar" AND "power". At that point everyone suggested Pipes.

Here's the pipe : http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ad1986b6e11677bbc84fe8c27a854812

There's not much to it. First it filters on one set of words, then another, which performs the AND. However, the end result is not at all expected. I still get all sorts of output for articles that don't contain any of the terms.

For instance, when I look right now I see three topics in the output:

Intel's Haswell-E Desktop CPU Debuts With Eight Cores, DDR4 Memory
Japanese Publishers Lash Out At Amazon's Policies
How the World's Fastest Electric Car Is Pushing Wireless Charging Tech

The last one is marginally related I supposed, but the first two don't seem to have anything to do with any of the filter terms.

Can anyone offer any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Yahoo pipes, you mean?

Comment: The topic of this post is "Yahoo pipes..." and the URL points to Yahoo. So, yes.

Comment: your title said otherwise. http://superuser.com/posts/805064/revisions